# Not getting proper output with Regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a below sentence, I need to extract it and get the proper output.

```
Welcome to project, are you a here(1. new user one, 2. test user two, 3. minor Accident one or 4. Major Accident)
```

I am getting the output now using regular expression:-

```
Welcome to project, are you a here
1. new user
2. test user
3. minor Accident or
4. Major
```

I should get the output as per sentence using regular expression:-

```
Welcome to project, are you a here
1. new user one
2. test user two
3. minor Accident one
4. Major Accident
```

Here is the code below,updated in plnker which I have used,I am not getting solution since I don't have that much idea in redular expression.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  regex = /.+\(|\d. [\w\s]+ /g;
  maintext = "Welcome to project, are you a here(1. new user one, 2. test user two, 3. minor Accident one or 4. Major Accident)";
  matches = maintext.match(regex);
  text_split0 = matches[0].slice(0, -1);
  text_split1 = matches[1];
  text_split2 = matches[2];
  text_split3 = matches[3];
  text_split4 = matches[4];
  console.log(text_split0);
  console.log(text_split1);
  console.log(text_split2);
  console.log(text_split3);
  console.log(text_split4);
  $(".messages").append('<li>' + text_split0 + '</li><li>' + text_split1 + '</li><li>' + text_split2 + '</li><li>' + text_split3 + '</li><li>' + text_split4 + '</li>');
  // $("li:contains('undefined')").remove()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="messages">
</ul>
```

Comment: What part of the regexp is supposed to prevent matching `one` and `two`?

Comment: I should get the output  same as the text inside the bracket as I mentioned above,I am getting properly which  outside bracket .but not getting properly inside one

Comment: Is there a general rule about what words should be skipped when matching? Or is it just `one` and `two`?

Comment: Your code isn't returning the output you say you're getting.

Comment: Yes comma and or should skip inside bracket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating one unicorn regex; do it in two steps. Simplify the regex to just finding the numbers. So you are matching just this:

https://regex101.com/r/BXf1IM/1

```
"1. new user one, 2. test user two, 3. minor Accident one or 4. Major Accident"
```

Then it will be easier to split that string by the numbers.

```
list.split(/([\d]. )/g)
```

Then you can loop through those to append it to an order list.

```
<ol class="messages">
    <li>new user one</li>
    <li>test user two</li>
    <li>minor Accident one or </li>
    <li>Major Accident</li>
</ol>
```

You'll need to clean up the " or " on the third item.

Full script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="messages"></ul>
<script>
    var text = 'Welcome to project, are you a here(1. new user one, 2. test user two, 3. minor Accident one or 4. Major Accident)';
    var regex = /\((.*)\)/;
    var m;

    if ((m = regex.exec(text)) !== null) {
        console.log(m[1]);
        // 1. new user one, 2. test user two, 3. minor Accident one or 4. Major Accident
        var list = m[1];

        var items = list.split(/([\d]. )/g);

        var message = $('.messages');



        // Remove ' or ' from secondLastItem by removing the last 4 characters
        var secondLastItem = items[items.length-3];
        items[items.length-3] = secondLastItem.substring(0, secondLastItem.length - 4);

        for(var i=1;i<items.length;i++) {
            // Ordered list
            // message.append('<li>' + items[++i].replace(', ', '') + '</li>');
            // Unordered list
            message.append('<li>' + items[i] + items[++i].replace(', ', '') + '</li>');
        }
    }

    // The intro text
    var introText = text.split('(');
    console.log(introText[0]);
</script>
```

Comment: I need to get the sentence which is outside of bracket also, welcome to project...

Comment: Numeric 1,2... Should come from sentence not from ol.. Can u pls help me

Comment: @carreankush I updated the code to use UL and the numbers from the regex.

Comment: @carreankush For the intro text, just split on the first '('

Comment: Thanks for your help.is it possible to remove 'or' from second last <li>

Comment: sure, no problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184113/discussion-between-stillatmylinux-and-carreankush).